# What if more than one regular expression matches a prefix of the remaining input?

Tags: java, regex, javacc

I came across this question while trying to use javacc which implement regular expression in its lexical analysis
He gave to me an example but its not clear to me.
Can anyone give me an example to it so that i can understand easily.
?

@Edit

Source:
http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? From a theoretical stand point, any string can be matched by an infinite amount of patterns.

Comment: @npinti did you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two principles that govern how JavaCC picks one regular expression over another.

The first is often called the "longest match" or "maximal munch" rule. This says that if regular expression *x* matches a longer prefix of the remaining input than regular expression *y* does, then regular expression *x* is preferred.

Example of the longest match rule.  Suppose that there are two regular expression productions

```
TOKEN : { <INT_LIT: ( ["1"-"9"] )+ > }
TOKEN : { <FLOAT_LIT: ( ["1"-"9"] )+ "." ( ["1"-"9"] )* > }
```

And suppose the remaining input is `"123.456abcdef"`. The `INT_LIT` regular expression matches the first 3 characters. (It also matches the first 1 and 2 characters, but we are only interested in the maximum length prefix that the expression matches.) The `FLOAT_LIT` matches the first 7 characters. 7 is bigger than 3, so the `FLOAT_LIT` is preferred over `INT_LIT`.

Here is another example:

```
TOKEN : { <ALL_CAPS: ( ["A"-"Z","_"] )+ > }
TOKEN : { <ALL_LOWER_CASE: ( ["a"-"z","_"] )+ > }
```

Now if the remaining input is `"_ABC"`, the first is preferred by the longest match rule. And if the remaining input is `"_abc"`, the second is preferred by the longest match rule.  But suppose that the remaining input is `"_123"`. Both rules match the 1 character prefix, so the longest match rule is no help.

The second principle is that when the longest match rule is no help because of a tie. The tie is broken according to which regular expression appears first in the .jj file.  In this case `ALL_CAPS` is preferred over `ALL_LOWER_CASE`.